# How to reshape long to wide dataframe panda, after filling the missed value per category?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following sample dataset

```
df  = pd.DataFrame({'Id': {0:'user_id1', 1:'user_id1', 2:'user_id1', 3:'user_id1',
                          4:'user_id2', 5:'user_id2',  6:'user_id2'},

                   'hr' :{0:1, 1:2, 2:3, 3:4, 4:1, 5:2, 6:3},
                   'value': {0:17, 1:20, 2:12, 3:10, 4:11, 5:20, 6:13},
                   'result': {0:12, 1:21, 2:32, 3:16, 4:41, 5:50, 6:53}})
df
```

[image]

First: Every user should have value at *result* and *value* column at every hour (*hr*). But if there is no *value* or *result*, then I should create the missed hour (*hr*) and add a new row with the median value for each column. The hour is always in the range from 1 to 4.

Example:- *user_id2* doesn't have a record at *hr = 4*. So, I will take the median of the other hours from *result* column i.e :

> np.median([[41, 50, 53]) => 50.

Similarly for *value* column:

> np.median([11, 20, 13]) = 13

This will result with a new row added for *user_id2* at *hr = 4* as shown below:
[image]

Finally: I want to convert the above long format into a wider so that every *user_id{i}* will have all values represented in a single vector [raw] per *hr* as shown below:
[image]

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

1) Use [`pandas.MultiIndex.from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to create the missing rows. Then use [`DataFrame.groupby.median`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.median.html) to create your [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) values

```
midx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['Id'].unique(), [1, 2, 3, 4]], names=['Id', 'hr'])
medians = df.groupby('Id').median()
df_new = df.set_index(['Id', 'hr']).reindex(midx).fillna(medians).reset_index()
```

2) Reshape your `DataFrame` using a combination of [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html)

```
df_new = df_new.set_index(['Id', 'hr']).stack().unstack([1, 2])
df_new.sort_index(axis=1, level=[0, 1])
```

3) Fix the column names with a list comprehension

```
df_new.columns = ['hr_{}_{}'.format(x[0], x[1]) for x in df_new.columns]
```

[out]

```
         hr_1_value  hr_1_result  hr_2_value  hr_2_result  hr_3_value  hr_3_result  hr_4_value  hr_4_result
Id                                                                                                                 
user_id1        17.0         12.0        20.0         21.0        12.0        32.0        10.0         16.0
user_id2        11.0         41.0        20.0         50.0        13.0        53.0        13.0         50.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.Id.unique(), df.hr.unique()],
                                       names=['Id', 'hr'])

df = df.set_index(['Id', 'hr']).reindex(new_index)

# fillna
new_df = (df.groupby('Id')
            .apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.median()))
            .unstack(level=1)
         )

new_df.columns = [f'hr_{b}_{a}' for a,b in new_df.columns]
```

Comment: 'new_df.columns = [f'hr_{b}_{a}' for a,b in new_df.columns]' I think this line has syntax error. Some comment on the function would also help. Appricate  :)

Comment: problem might be the format string: `f'hr_{b}_{a}'`, which is equivalent to `'hr_{}_{}`.format(b,a)` and which is only available in later version of python 3.x (don't remember exact number). So you can try the classic `.format` syntax.

Comment: yap, this works, 
    new_df.columns = ['hr_{}_{}'.format(a, b) for a,b in new_df.columns]